# Update each element within array within single function

Tags: javascript

I have below array object -

```
[
{
 index:0,
 value:"Yes",
},
{
 index:1,
 value:"No",
},
{
 index:2,
 value:"No",
},
{
 index:3,
 value:"Yes",
},
]
```

I want to update value of each element in array with "NA"

I tried doing -

```
obj.map(x=>{
x.value="NA"
});
```

This is not working.

Comment: You're not returning anything from the `map` callback. Try `return x;` after you've set the value. Note: `map` returns a _new_ array. You may want `forEach` which can mutate the array instead - depends on your use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two ways

`forEach`, which would mutate the existing array

```js
const obj = [
  {
    index: 0,
    value: "Yes",
  },
  {
    index: 1,
    value: "No",
  },
  {
    index: 2,
    value: "No",
  },
  {
    index: 3,
    value: "Yes",
  },
]

obj.forEach(x => {
  x.value = "NA"
})

console.log(obj)
```

`map`, which will return the new array

```js
const obj = [
  {
    index: 0,
    value: "Yes",
  },
  {
    index: 1,
    value: "No",
  },
  {
    index: 2,
    value: "No",
  },
  {
    index: 3,
    value: "Yes",
  },
]

const newObj = obj.map(x => ({
  ...x,
  value: "NA",
}))

console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: can I assign it within same array ? (with map) .. Like - obj=obj.map(..

Comment: That's not how you should be using `map`. `map` transforms an array into a _new_ array. @CSharper

Comment: @CSharper yes, you could, but you should not. Usually, `map` is used to create a new array based on the provided callback function (avoid mutation), while `forEach` is used only to execute the function on each element (mutation is okay)

Answer (score 1):

There are two points need to pay attention:

1. you need to assign the result to a new variable after using `map`
2. inside the `map` function,we also need to return the mapped object via `return`

```js
let data = [
{
 index:0,
 value:"Yes",
},
{
 index:1,
 value:"No",
},
{
 index:2,
 value:"No",
},
{
 index:3,
 value:"Yes",
},
]

let result = data.map(d =>{
  d.value="NA"
  return d
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = [
{
 index:0,
 value:"Yes",
},
{
 index:1,
 value:"No",
},
{
 index:2,
 value:"No",
},
{
 index:3,
 value:"Yes",
},
]

let arr= data.map(x =>{
  x.value="NA"
  return x
})

console.log(arr)
```

or with the old way

```
for(let i=0;i<data.lenght;i++){
data[i].value='na'
}
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Small advice,before post answer,need to check others have posted the same or not

Comment: @lucumt Small advice,before post answer,need to check others have posted the same or not

Comment: Hey,why do you copy my comments, your answer is 4 minutes later posted than me and is the same with mine,so try to avoid the duplicate answer